# I need help in converting a dictionary to plaintext and then writing this data to a text file

Tags: python

I'm making a program that saves user data into a text file.
Currently I'm using a dictionary to be referenced throughout the entire program, and when the user quits the program, it takes all the data from the dictionary and writes it into the text file. While I have most of the program working, I'm having a bit of trouble writing the actual end data into the text file. If you could help me, I would appreciate it alot!

I'm also quite new to programming as a whole so sorry if any of my coding habits are bad.

```
lis = []
for new_k, new_v in dictionary.items():
    lis.append([new_k, new_v])
            
    output = (" ".join(map(str, lis)))
    acc = open("Storage.txt", "w")
    acc.write(lis)
```

Comment: Also I need to keep it in a text file because there is a login/create account function I made.

Comment: Open the file before entering the for-loop (and close it afterwards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how you can open the file and write a string to it

```
dictionary = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

lis = []

with open("Storage.txt", "w") as acc:
    for new_k, new_v in dictionary.items():
        lis.append([new_k, new_v])
                
        output = (" ".join(map(str, lis)))
        acc.write(output)
```

However, this code does not behave well as it writes the same data in each iteration of the for loop, which is why I recommend you instead move the file I/O after you have created your list like so

```
dictionary = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

lis = []


for new_k, new_v in dictionary.items():
    lis.append([new_k, new_v])

with open("Storage.txt", "w") as acc:               
    for sublist in lis:
        acc.write('{}, {}\n'.format(str(sublist[0]), str(sublist[1])))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! While it does now write to the file, it doesn't format it correctly.  This is how it is supposed to look like: admin, 0 This is how it actually formats it: ['admin', 0]

Comment: The reason I need it formatted like that is because the code detects whether or not that username is already taken

Comment: For reference, this is how each account is created:               
accounts.write(createAcc + ", " + "0" + "\n")

Comment: @JamesSmith I have changed the code to reflect this

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I have been debugging this for over 24 hours so far.. You are a life saver! :)